# Passing values from ajax page to calling page javascript function

Tags: php, ajax

One part of my page is being loaded via ajax using jquery. For example this initial page has a name *first.php*. It has a div with it's innerHTML generated from ajax called script (for example ajax is calling *second.php*). Is it possible to pass some values from ajax executed script *(second.php)* to original site. I need to access this value from original site (the one calling second script via ajax) javascript function, and I don't want to use hidden fields.

For example, my site has some captcha that is being displayed and processed through ajax. I don't want to write captcha result to some hidden field and access it with original site javascript function because of possible javascript injection attack...

Comment: Are the two files on different domains?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you call your secound.php script via ajax, you surely could read the result.

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'secound.php',
  success: function(data) {
    // now data contains the code returned by secound.php
  }
});
```

Now the most common way to return data from your secound.php script is returning it in JSon format. Then you could do someting like:

```
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
alert(obj.name);
```

For this example your secound.php needs to return

```
{"name":"John"}
```